# Efficient way to format my text file

Tags: c#, .net, text-files

I have log file with around 2000 lines in it. I have gone through first round of formatting. However, I met with difficulty to format my log to what I want for the moment:

**Current:**

```
line1: 9/13/2011 3:58:05 AM, abef, 1234, ...
line2: 9/14/2011 3:58:05 AM, adef, 1234, ...
line3:
line4: 9/15/2011 3:58:05 AM, bcdef, 134, ...
line5: 3) sdad
line6: azd
line7: [] asdsdee234 
line2014: 9/16/2011 3:58:05 AM, abcf, 1234, ...
```

What I want to achieve is to clean up the log to remove lines that do not begin with a date. So line 3, 5, 6 and 7 need to be removed.

**Wanted result:**

```
line1: 9/13/2011 3:58:05 AM, abef, 1234, ...
line2: 9/14/2011 3:58:05 AM, adef, 1234, ...
line3: 9/15/2011 3:58:05 AM, bcdef, 134, ...
line2010: 9/16/2011 3:58:05 AM, abcf, 1234, ...
```

Comment: This question is too broad. Please identify what you were trying and where you got stuck. (And please read the stackoverflow docs to format your data correctly.)

Comment: efficient does not mean correct :) do you really care about code being optimal *before* geting it to do what you want?

Comment: I have tried, reading all the lines in the textfile, put them in list<string>, check whether each line begin with a date. (here i stuck), and not sure how to remove if the line does not begin with a date format. Note: all line are Strings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
private static IEnumerable<string> ReadOnlyDateTime(string path)
{
    DateTime d;
    string input;
    using (StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(path)) 
    {
        while ((input = stream.ReadLine() != null && DateTime.TryParse(input, out d))
        {
            yield return input;
        }
    }
}
```

or

```
DateTime d;
IList<string> = File.ReadLines(path)
                    .Where(line => DateTime.TryParse(line, out d)
                    .ToList();
```

Then dump result to disk using `File.WriteAllLines()`.

Comment: @abatischev: thanks for your reply. However if you dont mind, may you check the post again? i edited. All lines are string, therefore i do not think tryparse works.

Comment: +1. @10e5x, please provide reason why you "don't think `TryParse` works with strings"...

Comment: @10e5x TryParse method signature:  `public static bool TryParse(string s, out DateTime result)`

Comment: @10e5x: Indeed, it will not work. Then use RegEx like `^(.+), .+, ...$` and get date-time part first. Then parse is by RegEx too or by DateTime.TryParse().

Comment: i got the regex expression for MM/DD/yyyy already but i unable to find regex expression for M/DD/yyyy as i have dates like 9/14/2012 ....

Comment: @10e5x: Try `^([0-9]+{1,2})\/([0-9]+{1,2})\/([0-9]{4}).+$`, [should work](http://www.rubular.com/r/yHVBNXMKgH)

Answer (score 1):

When you are iterating through each line of the file in your code, you have two options to check for the date:

- Evaluate the `string` using [regular expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hs600312.aspx).
- [DateTime.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch92fbc1.aspx) the `string`.